# How do I open in-app browser window in React native?

Tags: react-redux, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to open the browser window without leaving the app when I click a URL (for both iOS and Android).

The behavior should be as follows (with airbnb app example):

- Clicks in "Terms and conditions" link: [links example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4esEA.png)
- Open the browser in-app:
- For iOS: [in-app browser iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCwSK.png)
- Same for Android.

How can I do this? Do I need to use any specified existing library?

I'm using react-native 0.37.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the new [InAppBrowser plugin for React Native](https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser), check the next example:

```js
import { Linking } from 'react-native'
import InAppBrowser from 'react-native-inappbrowser-reborn';

...
  async openLink() {
    try {
      const isAvailable = await InAppBrowser.isAvailable()
      const url = 'https://www.google.com'
      if (isAvailable) {
        InAppBrowser.open(url, {
          // iOS Properties
          dismissButtonStyle: 'cancel',
          preferredBarTintColor: 'gray',
          preferredControlTintColor: 'white',
          // Android Properties
          showTitle: true,
          toolbarColor: '#6200EE',
          secondaryToolbarColor: 'black',
          enableUrlBarHiding: true,
          enableDefaultShare: true,
          forceCloseOnRedirection: true,
        }).then((result) => {
          Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(result))
        })
      } else Linking.openURL(url)
    } catch (error) {
      Alert.alert(error.message)
    }
  }
...
```

On the other hand, you can use this plugin with deep linking, check the README of the project.

Comment: How can I control this with something like onNavigationStateChange which is available for a simple webview?

Comment: Using Linking of React Native directly

Comment: In my case, i tried for Amazon payment page. In android, its opening new tabs when the webview needs.But in IOS, it dont allow to open new tabs. So after loggedin the page shows just a blank page:(! Temporarily i used *deep-linking * and *react-native-custom-tabs*

Comment: @Johncy oh I understand, it's limited by Safari Services :(

Comment: @jdnichollsc i can see in-app browsers in iOS doing the same payment gateway in some apps like airtel, bookmyshow etc..Still am not able to understand how to achieve that on iOS :( If anyone having idea please post your suggession

Comment: @Johncy please post your issue from the repo :) https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser/issues

Answer (score 5):

### Opens Safa Module Method

On iOS `SafariView` 3rd party native module - https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-safari-view

On Android `CustomTabs` 3rd party native module - https://github.com/droibit/react-native-custom-tabs - however if the user does not have Chrome installed, it will pop open the link outside of your app in their default browser.

### Alternative WebView Method

You can use a `<WebView>` but this is not using the real browser  - http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.47/docs/webview.html#webview

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native';

class MyWeb extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{uri: 'https://github.com/facebook/react-native'}}
        style={{marginTop: 20}}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I already try this, but isn't the native view as shown in the example. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @FacundoBazzana check out update. I found ios and android solution.

Comment: WebView is no longer available in react-native package :(

Comment: This webview will not handle deep links. when you click on any link or button in side the webview, it will redirects it to native browser. we cannot run the entire websites inside the webview like iframes.

Answer (score 3):

Use [React Native Custom Tabs](https://github.com/droibit/react-native-custom-tabs) to open in-app browser window in React native. It support both platform **Android** and **iOS**

Answer (score 3):

You can use [React Native In-App Browser Reborn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-inappbrowser-reborn). It works perfectly on both Android and iOS.

This library use `react-native-safari-view` (SafariView) on iOS and `react-native-custom-tabs` (ChromeView) on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Use native react native linking to open a url

> https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking